# How to capture Heap Dumps with AppDynamics?

Tags: heap-dump, performance-monitor, appdynamics

How can we capture heap dumps with the help of appdynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from their documentation, AppD do not have a way to capture heap dumps. They suggest using Memory Leak detection feature in such scenarios.
On a different note, I know we can get thread dumps which maybe helpful in some cases (Agents -> Request Agent Log Files)

Answer (score 8):

Heap dumps in appdynamics can be taken for JRockit JVM by the below method(Note : This does not work for IBM JVM)

- Select your node in appdynamics for which the heap dump has to be taken.
- Select the tab "JMX"
- Go to "MBean Browser"
- Go to "com.sun.management" >> "HotSpotDiagnostic" from the left pane
- On the right window under operations for dumpHeap click on the thunderbolt sign to invoke action.
- A new dialogue box opens up in which you have to fill the p0 and p1 text boxes as follows

p0 – Path to generate heap dump(/path/dump.hprof)

p1 -  True – GC before Heap dump ; False - No GC before heap dump

- Click on "invoke"

Note : If you want heap dump to be generated in the case of out of memory give

p0 : HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Also note that these values will be lost on JVM restart.